# Uniform bound on time derivative in Galerkin method for parabolic PDE (need explanation of text)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am asking about a passage in the book

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3e4h1j9WNlwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=james+robinson+infinite+dimensional&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WlLJUZHUIePU0QXu04CwDw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

please see page 203.

My question is, suppose we have a PDE
$$u' + Au = f$$
that we solve by using the Galerkin method. The Galerkin approximation satisfies
$$(u_n', w_j) + (Au_n, w_j) = (f,w_j)\tag{1}$$
for $j=1,...,n$, where $w_j$ is the basis.
According to this book, we can write this as
$$u_n' + Au_n = f\tag{2}$$
but what space is this an equality in? The book seems to suggest $L^2(0,T;V')$, but (1) only holds for the basis functions and hence I can only see the equality holds for $L^2(0,T;V_n')$, where $V_n$ is the span of the first $n$ basis functions.

And then, the author gets an uniform estimate on $\lVert u_n'\rVert_{L^2(0,T;V')}$ by using the fact that $f, Au_n \in L^2(0,T;V')).$ I understand this follows if the equality (2) were to hold in $L^2(0,T;V')$ but if it only holds in $L^2(0,T;V_n')$ does it follow?

---

I posted a thread about something similar to this previously but I think this is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem in understand equality $(2)$ as an equality in $V'$, in fact remember that  $V\subset H\subset V'$ is a Hilbert triple.

If I got the right notation in the book, there they consider $A=-\Delta$, $V=H_0^1$ and $H=L^2$. Now, in one hand, as I have said in first paragraph, $u'_n\in V\subset V'$. On other hand $Au_n\in H\subset V'$, so you can see the equality in $V'$.

Remark: We want to solve the equation $$u'+Au=f\tag{1}$$

Let $P_n$ be the projection onto $V_n$ and applies it in both sides of $(1)$: $$\tag{2} P_nu'+P_n Au=P_nf$$

If we write $u$ in terms of the eigenvector of $A=-\Delta$, i.e $u=\sum \lambda_k w_k$, then $P_nAu=Au_n$ where $u_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_ kw_k$, hence $(2)$ is equivalently to $$\tag{3} u'_n+Au_n=f_n$$

where $f_n=P_N f$ and $(3)$ is your equation $(1)$. Now you can note that if you solve your equation in $V'_n$, then the same equation is true in $V'$. This is because if you take any elment in $v\in V$ that belongs to $\operatorname{span}\{w_{n+1},...\}$, you have that $$\tag{4}(P_n u',v)=(P_n Au,v)=(P_n f,v)=0$$

Remark 2: I'm gonna show here that $(1)$ of Op is equivalently of my $(2)$.

I - $(1)$ implies $(2)$

Note that $(1)$ implies $$\tag{5}(u'_n,w)+(Au_n,w)=(f,w), \ \forall \ w\in V_n$$

From $(5)$ we conclude that $$\tag{6}(Pu'_n,w)+(APu_n,w)=(f,P_nw),\ \forall w\in V_n$$

Note that (by definition) $(P_nf, w)=(f,P_nw)$, so by applying the same argument as in $(4)$ to the equation $(6)$ we conclude that $$(P_nu'_n)+(P_nAu_n,w)=(P_nf,w),\ \forall w\in V$$

From the last equality we conclude that $(3)$ is true.

II - $(2)$ implies $(1)$

Just apply $w_j$ in both sides and note that $(P_nf,w_j)=(f,P_nw_j)=(f,w_j)$.

Comment: I agree that $Au_n \in L^2(0,T;V')$, $u_n' \in L^2(0,T;V')$, and $f \in L^2(0,T;V')$. But why is true that $u_n' = Au_n + f$ in $L^2(0,T;V')$? I just don't understand why that equality holds.

Comment: I am asking why adding $Au_n$ to $f$ equals $u_n'.$

Comment: @workl take a look and see if you get convinced now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have to say I am still not sure.. remember equation (1) (in your post) holds in a weak sense only so it not that clear to me that you can just apply the projection operator like that.

Comment: Applying the projection operator to $(1)$ is unnecessary for my conclusion (although it is valid). I have used it only as as heuristic point of view, beucase what I really want to show you was that $(2)$ is equivalently to $(3)$ and this is always true.

Comment: OK. Could you maybe explain how I can obtain your equation (2) from my equation (1)?

Comment: @workl, I have updated my answer, take a look on it.

Comment: Thank you. So I see that the property $V = V_m + V_m^{\perp}$ is used..

Comment: Yes I have used it all the time: remember that $w_n$ is orthogonal in $V,H$ and $D(-\Delta)$.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer. Before accepting let me wait a while to see maybe other solutions.

Comment: You are welcome @workl.

Comment: @workl Hmm...I remembered answering one of your question not long ago. What puzzles me most is that: $u - P_n u \in \{w_{n+1},\ldots\}\not \subset V_n^{\perp}$ necessarily, unless we assumed that $\{w_i\}^{\infty}_{i=1}$ is a set of orthonormal basis, but you didn't mention $\{w_i\}$ is orthogonal (for example $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$), can we use this property here?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Indeed but that question was slightly different. 

I am ultimately interested in the case that $w_j$ are not orthogonal, but I did not understand the argument in this book I cited (where the author uses orthogonal basis), so I asked it to understand the method. I can't seem to get it to work without the basis being orthogonal unfortunately.. So I am wondering whether there is a more general answer that does not use the basis.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao, by the spctral theorem for unbounded operators, $w_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$ and a complete orthogonal system of $D(A)$. With some additional calculations,it can be proved also that $w_n$ is  a complete orthogonal system to $V$.

Comment: Suppose I did not want to use a orthonormal/orthogonal basis (even though I know one can always get one), are you aware of a way to do this?

Comment: @workl I doubt that, orthogonality sure has huge usage here. What I have in mind is Whitney forms in a simplicial complex, then $(u-P_n u, w_i)\neq 0$ for any $w_i$, where $i\leq n$ being the basis...

Comment: @Tomás It is indeed true that we can diagonalize $A$ in $H$ but my question was that: "Is $\{w_i\}$ the basis set where $A$ is diagonal?" I guess in this case it is indeed.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao, I see and as you have said orthogonality is strongly used here.